# How to insert a row of data to a table using Django's ORM

Tags: django, django-models

How do I insert data in Django to a SQL table using the Django ORM?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you need to insert a row of data, see the "[Saving objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects)" documentation for the `save` method on the model.

FYI, you can perform a bulk insert. See the [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create) method's documentation.

Answer (score 12):

In fact it's mentioned in the first part of the "[Writing your first Django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)" tutorial.

As mention in the "Playing with API" section:

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> p = Poll(question="What's new?", pub_date=timezone.now())

# Save the object into the database. You have to call save() explicitly.
>>> p.save()

# Now it has an ID. Note that this might say "1L" instead of "1", depending
# on which database you're using. That's no biggie; it just means your
# database backend prefers to return integers as Python long integer
# objects.
>>> p.id
1
```

[Part-4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/)  of the tutorial explains how to use forms and how to save object using user submitted data.

Comment: @user1590011, you can execute similar statements in views etc. Look at part4 of tutorial.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to call the save() method explicitly, you can create a record by using `MyModel.objects.create(p1=v1, p2=v1, ...)`

```
fruit = Fruit.objects.create(name='Apple')
# get fruit id
print(fruit.id)
```

[See documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/)